# Using different payment methods in google play store distributed app

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play

I want to sell premium accounts through In-app purchases in my android application. Am I allowed to use different payment methods (like PayPal and Paymill) instead of Google Play In-app billing?

It seems that subscription payments are only allowed using the payment method provided by Google (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#payment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in the Developer Content Policy:

> ◦Developers offering virtual goods or currencies within a game
>   downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing
>   service as the method of payment.

https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: I found some apps on play store using their own payment methods (Not google wallet) for subscription of app license. So why google is allowing them to use that payment methods.

Comment: @TusharMate Google probably does not know it. I don't think, they check millions of apps manually every day.

Answer (score 2):

Google has recently announced that it now supports PayPal as a payment method. The best part is that if you have implemented in-app purchase you don't have to do anything extra for enabling PayPal support. Details can be found [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/05/helping-you-go-global-with-more.html)